# How to perform array operations in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, xlwings

I am manipulating excel worksheets and need to compare two data sets elementwise, and test if they are all equal. So I type in cell C1 "=AND(A1:A3=B1:B3)". Unfortunately the function only compares A1 with B1 and ignore the rest. Is there a way to make Excel understand such an obvious intention? Thank you for any help.

P.S. Please don't suggest to drag the mouse over a range, or hold Ctrl while pressing Enter. I am generating worksheets from a script, not by hand. All I can do is put text string in a cell.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Comment: You need an array formula.  So instead of just pressing the enter key when you type in the formula use control-shift-enter.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am using xlwings to do the manipulation. I cannot instruct xlwings to "press CSE", I can only put text commands in the cell. In other words, I need a programmable way for doing it.

Comment: So do it in Excel using Ctrl+Shift+Enter, and look at the formula it generates. You'll then know what you need to do programmatically as the equivalent. You clearly have a copy of Excel, as you say *So I type in cell*. If you're able to *type in cell*, you're capable of using the keyboard to figure out what the formula should look like to properly include a range, right?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The formula included a pair of {} as an indicator of "array operations". Unfortunately by manually adding a pair of {} in the formula does not turn the formula into "array" formula. I had to press CSE by hand. In fact, if I click into that cell with the CSE formula, the pair of {} disappear! I need to press CSE again to get it back! No way to use text only :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write array formulas via xlwings, see the [docs](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range.formula_array). As an example:

```
>>> import xlwings as xw
>>> xw.Range('A1:A3').value = 1  # some sample data
>>> xw.Range('B1:B3').formula_array = '=A1:A3+1'
```

When you now click on cell B1, you'll see the familiar `{}` around your array formula.